# How to escape quotes while inserting data in database in JOOMLA 2.5

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

I am trying to insert data in database(mysql) but not successful when i am trying to add data with single or double quotes.Its working fine otherwise(without Quote). I know we have to use `mysql_real_escape_string` in such situations.But i am using joomla framework where this function is not working.

My code is below:

```
function insert($table, $array) {
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
 $query = "INSERT INTO ".$table;
  $fis = array();
  $vas = array();
  foreach($array as $field=>$val) {

 if(is_array($val)){
 $x= implode(",",$val);
 }
 else
 {
 $x=$val;
 }

   $fis[] = "`$field`";//you must verify keys of array outside of function;
                         //unknown keys will cause mysql errors;
                         //there is also sql injection risc;
    $vas[] = "'".$x."'";
  }
$query .= " (".implode(", ", $fis).") VALUES (".implode(", ", $vas).")";
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
}
insert('#__storage_companies',JRequest::get( 'post' ));
```

Please tell me how to get rid of this.

Comment: It giving me this error DB function failed with error number 1064

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [JDatabaseDriver::quote](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/Database/JDatabaseDriver.html#methodquote). Used like `$db->quote($value)`.
Also to quote field names, use `$db->quoteName($value)`.

Take a look at [Preparing the query](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase#Preparing_the_query) from the Joomla wiki.

You code should be like:

```php
$fis[] = $db->nameQuote($field);
$vas[] = $db->quote($x);
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you not escape the quotes yourself?

Just do:

```
$val = str_replace(array("'", '"'), array("\\'", '\\"'), $val);
```

Comment: While the question was specific to some JFactory Code, your answer, which is more generic helped me! Thanks.

Comment: Watch out using this code in production. It is insecure!
Think about when someone enters '\\/**/' into a field, which is just one example.